# How can I get R to count every time a value is within 10 numbers of each other in a data set?

Tags: r

I would like R to count every time an X or Y value in a data set is within 10 numbers of each other. My dataset appears like this:

Point 1: X: 30, Y: 34
Point 2: X 35, Y: 30
Point 3: X 10, Y: 10

```r
d <- data.frame(
  X = c(30, 35, 10),
  Y = c(34, 30, 10)
)
d
#>    X  Y
#> 1 30 34
#> 2 35 30
#> 3 10 10
```

I would like R to count Point 1 and 2 being next to each other.

This is what I have so far:

```
def distance
count = length of data set
nested for loop
for d in data
    for p in list
        if distance(d[0], d[1], p[0], p[1]) ==0:
        continue
        Élif distance < 12 and distance != 0:
         count -= 1
```

Comment: @Gizmo62 pls show us what u have tried.

Comment: Why is this tagged `python` ? Please add data using `dput` or something that we can copy and use. Also show expected output for the data shared. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Something like: `abs(x - y) < 10 & (x != y)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if two values are within some tolerance you can use the absolute value of their difference, which in R is

```r
abs(a - b) <= tolerance
```

The `lag()` function returns the lagged value (some number of indices prior) so you can use that to see if a value is within some value of the previous one. You can calculate this for your two columns

```r
d$x_within_10 <- abs(lag(d$X) - d$X) <= 10
d$y_within_10 <- abs(lag(d$Y) - d$Y) <= 10 
d
#>    X  Y x_within_10 y_within_10
#> 1 30 34          NA          NA
#> 2 35 30        TRUE        TRUE
#> 3 10 10       FALSE       FALSE
```

The first row has nothing previous to compare to so that result is NA.